# Reputation changes not being shown after account Connection

Tags: bug, reputation, user-accounts, openid, linked-accounts

I was just searching for my profiles on stackoverflow on Google, and I have one which I use a lot, but then I found another which was `Reputation 1`, which was an account created logging in with Facebook, then I connected them and the Reputation section it is showing: **You have no recent reputation changes**, of course my points aren't gone, but the Reputation section shouldn't change like that. I'll reproduce the steps I had.

- I have a Facebook account: `firstemail@hotmail.com`
- I have a Google account: `secondemail@gmail.com`
- I logged in to Stackoverflow (and created account) with the Google account.
- I logged in to Stackoverflow (and created account) with the Facebook account.
- Now I have two Stackoverflow accounts.
- I started using Stackoverflow with the Google account.
- The Facebook account remained with Reputation 1.
- I changed my Facebook email to `secondemail@gmail.com`.
- Now when I try to log in to Stackoverflow with Facebook, it connected my two accounts, deleting the account with Reputation 1, and even updating my Stackoverflow picture. The reputation Section is showing **You have no recent reputation changes**, event though I had activity yesterday.

This isn't affecting me, just that that section is showing no events on my reputation, but my reputation remains the same, and I wonder, when this happens, it always deletes the account with less points? or it was just because my second account wasn't being used?

Thank you.

Comment: If I'm reading your account history correctly, it appears that a system merge occurred.  This can happen as a result of you personally requesting a merge, or sometimes the system itself will merge accounts if it detects a duplicate one.

Comment: The system did it.

Comment: Can you link to where this is happening?  I don't see any of your users with an issue.

Comment: The Reputation section view changed after I made an activity, so it is not showing errors anymore. Could someone clarify what is the procedure to delete an account after linking?